# HTTPS for image_url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

Anyone know how to force rails to set image_url absolute path with https?

This is my view.

```
image_url @example.avatar.url(:original)
```

It gives me full path with http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with the following

```
request.protocol + request.host_with_port + @example.avatar.url(:original)
```

Where requested.protocol is forced by environment variable according to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you use `image_path` instead of `image_url` you will get a relative URL instead of an absolute one which will use https if the rest of the website is https.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `config/initializers/force_ssl.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```